# PHP Regex, Matching anything between two specific words/tags with conditions

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm poor in regex, here is my scenario,

I'm trying to extract some info from a webpage which contains several tables, only some of the tables contains a unique url (let's say "very/unique.key"), so it will looks like this:

```
<table ....>
   (bunch of content)
</table>

<table ....>
   (bunch of content)
</table>

<table ....>
   (bunch of content + "very/unique.key" keyword)
</table>

<table ....>
   (bunch of content)
</table>

<table ....>
   (bunch of content + "very/unique.key" keyword)
</table>
```

So what I want is to extract all tables' content that contains the "very/unique.key" keyword. And here are the pattern that I have tried:

`$pattern = "#<table[^>]+>((?!\<table)(?=very\/unique\.key).*)<\/table>#i";`

This returns nothing to me....

`$pattern = "#<table[^>]+>((?!<table).*)<\/table>#i";`

This will return me everything from table 1's open tag `<table...>` till the last table's close tag `</table>` even with the `(?!<table)` condition...

Appreciate anyone who are willing to help me on this, thanks.

--**EDIT**--

Here is the solution that I found using DOM to loop through every table

--***My Solution***--

```
    $index;//indexes of all the table(s) that contains the keyword
        $cd = 0;//counter

        $DOM = new DOMDocument();
        $DOM->loadHTMLFile("http://uni.corp/sub/sub/target.php?key=123");
        $xpath = new DomXPath($DOM);
        $tables = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("table");
        for ($n = 0; $n < $tables->length; $n++) {
            $rows = $tables->item($n)->getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for ($i = 0; $i < $rows->length; $i++) {
                $cols = $rows->item($i)->getElementsbyTagName("td");
                for ($j = 0; $j < $cols->length; $j++) {


                     $td = $cols->item($j); // grab the td element
                     $img = $xpath->query('./img',$td)->item(0); // grab the first direct img child element


                    if(isset($img) ){
                        $image = $img->getAttribute('src'); // grab the source of the image
                        echo $image;
                        if($image == "very/unique.key"){
                            echo $cols->item($j)->nodeValue, "\t";
                            $index[$cd] = $n;
                            if($n > $cd){
                                $cd++;
                            }


                            echo $cd . " " . $n;//for troubleshooting
                        }


                    }

                }
                echo "<br/>";
            }
        }   

        //loop that echo out only the table(s) that I want which contains the keyword
        $loop = sizeof($index);
        for ($n = 0; $n < $loop; $n++) {
            $temp = $index[$n];
            $rows = $tables->item($temp)->getElementsbyTagName("tr");
            for ($i = 0; $i < $rows->length; $i++) {
                $cols = $rows->item($i)->getElementsbyTagName("td");                
                for ($j = 0; $j < $cols->length; $j++) {
                    echo $cols->item($j)->nodeValue, "\t";
                    //proccess the extracted table content here
                }
                //echo "<br/>";
            }
        }
```

But personally, I'm still curious about the Regex part, wish anyone could found the solution of the regex pattern for this question. Anyway, thanks to everyone who are helping/advising me on this (especially to AbsoluteƵERØ).

Comment: why using regex in the first place ? what about : http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: This seems to be the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your real question/problem is how you can get the table elements that contain the mentioned string. Using a regex is just one solution that in addition doesn't really add up.

Comment: The Webpage that I'm trying to parse/extract is a dynamic page which using AJAX/php/JS to generate dynamic contents. Thus most html element within the webpage doesn't have any unique identifiers like id/class. And because the content is dynamic, so I feel that using DOM for parsing may be much more difficult, though I'm poor in regex as well. And this is an intranet webpage, I'm using it to parse for certain amount of info only which shouldn't be more than 1 month (I guess). Thanks for replying me and appreciate anyone could enlighten me more on this in either using DOM or Regex or whatever...

Answer (score 2):

This works in PHP5. We parse the tables and the use `preg_match()` to check for the key. The reason you would want to use a method like this is because `HTML` does not have to be written syntactically correct unlike `XML`. Because of this you may not actually have proper closing tags. Additionally you may have nested tables which would give you multiple results trying to match opening and closing tags with REGEX. This way we're only checking for the key itself and not good form of the document being parsed.

```
<?php

$input = "<html>
<table id='1'>
<tr>
<td>This does not contain the key.</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id='2'>
<tr>
<td>This does contain the unique.key!</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id='3'>
<tr>
<td>This also contains the unique.key.</td>
</tr>
</table>

</html>";

$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->loadHTML($input);

$findings = array();

$tables = $html->getElementsByTagName('table');
foreach($tables as $table){

    $element = $table->nodeValue;

    if(preg_match('!unique\.key!',$element)){
        $findings[] = $element;
    }
}

print_r($findings);

?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => This does contain the unique.key!
    [1] => This also contains the unique.key.
)
```

Comment: Newbie to DOM as well, but it seems good to use both of them. But I have 2 problems, 1) I need the whole table content that have the unique key instead of only the key, 2) Can I put something like "http://uni.corp/sub/sub/target.php?key=123" as the input for loadHTML()? Because it returns an empty array to me even I try to loop through every elements without any condition. But anyway, thanks for pointing me to a new direction, which is helpful, thanks again.

Comment: Done some idiot mistake previously, now the DOM part works nicely, just need to figure out the regex part, which is not working. Ahh, regex again, I hate regex... Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @user2619841 What's the exact key? Are you escaping it correctly?

Comment: As I mentioned above, it is a url like "sub/filename.ext", not sure why the regex is not working and return nothing to me, but thanks for guiding me to using DOM, I have found a solution to get the whole table content, check on my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Though I agree with the comments on your post, I will give the solution. If you wanted to replace the very/unique.key by something else, the correct regex would look something like this

```
#<table(.*)>((.*)very\/unique\.key(.*))<\/table>#imsU
```

The key here is to use the correct modifiers to make it work with your input string. FOr more information on these modifiers, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Now here's an example where I replace the very/unique.key by "foobar"

```
<?php
$string = "
<table ....>
   (bunch of content)
</table>

<table ....>
   (bunch of content)
</table>

<table ....>
   bunch of content very/unique.key 
</table>

<table ....>
   (bunch of content)
</table>

<table ....>
   blabla very/unique.key
</table>
";

$pattern = '#<table(.*)>((.*)very\/unique\.key(.*))<\/table>#imsU';

echo preg_replace($pattern, '<table$1>$3foobar$4</table>', $string);
?>
```

This code prints exactly the same string but with the two "very/unique.key" replaced by "foobar", just like we want.

Though this solution could work, it's certainly not the most efficient nor the easiest work with. Like Mehdi said in the comments, PHP has an extension specifically made to operate on XML (thus HTML).

Here's a link to the documentation of that extension
http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php

Using that, you could easily go through each table elements and find the ones that have the unique key.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but unfortunately, it return nothing to me :(, anyway, thanks again for willing to help

Comment: I edited my answer to provide more details and a more complete regex :)